# How to use delegate and event in multi-threading c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm experimenting with multi-thread coding. If I would like to execute processes in parallel. Say, I would like to query table A, table B, and table C simultaneously. Within each thread, I am doing SqlCommand .ExecuteReader like this:

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

```
namespace MultiThread2
{
    public class TableFieldArray
    {
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
    }

    static class MTProcess
    {
        const string connStr = "server=***;database=***;user id=***;password=***";

        public static event GetStringArrayResult OnRecordsFoundMTS;

        public static void GetStringArrays(TableFieldArray[] tableFieldArray)
        {
            foreach (TableFieldArray tf in tableFieldArray)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    ST_Process stp = new ST_Process(connStr);
                    stp.ListOfFieldValue(tf.TableName, tf.FieldName);
                    stp.OnRecordsFound += new GetStringArrayResult(getEvent);
                });

                thread.Start();
            }
        }

        private static void getEvent(string[] result)
        {
            OnRecordsFoundMTS(result);
            return;
        }

// ---------------

    public delegate void GetStringArrayResult(string[] output);

    class ST_Process
    {
        public event GetStringArrayResult OnRecordsFound;

        private readonly string _connStr;

        public ST_Process(string connectionString)
        {
            _connStr = connectionString;
        }

        public void ListOfFieldValue(string tableName, string fieldName)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                string sqlText = string.Format("SELECT TOP 100 {0} FROM {1} ", fieldName, tableName);
                using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, sqlConn) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text })
                {
                    var r = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        result.Add(r[fieldName].ToString());
                    }
                    OnRecordsFound(_result.ToArray());
                }
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when executed in separate threads, OnRecordsFound(_result.ToArray()) causes object reference not set to an instance of an object exception error. Any idea how to make this setup work with multi-thread environment?

Comment: You are sharing a `List<string>` between threads.  If any of those threads modify the list, you must manage access to it using `lock()`

Comment: Please include your calling code (with multiple calls to `ListOfFieldValue`).

Comment: I just pasted it in the original post, thank you Amy

Comment: Your current code in your question does not compile (sometimes you use `result`, sometimes `_result`). This makes it hard to give advice. _Also, please update with the full stack trace of the exception that occurs._

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    ST_Process stp = new ST_Process(connStr);
    stp.OnRecordsFound += new GetStringArrayResult(getEvent);
    stp.ListOfFieldValue(tf.TableName, tf.FieldName);
});
```

You need to subscribe to the event first.  Also, whenever calling events it is good practice to check for null:

```
var e = someEvent;
if (e != null)
    e();
```

Comment: This works, so the problem was not that the process was not sequential in each thread, but it was the += that needs to preceed the actual call to the method (ListOfFieldValue in this case) . And yes I agree that would be a good practice. Thank you Zer0!

Answer (score 2):

Instance methods of the `List<T>` class which write data (such as `Add`) are not thread safe, so cannot be used by multiple threads.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.1#Thread_Safety

> **Thread Safety**
>
> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization. For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace.

Instead, you should use a thread-safe collection class such as `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, assuming that your three threads are invoking ListOfFielfValue on the same object, it looks like your multiple threads are all writing to a shared variable, _result. You need to make this a local variable in the method.

Objects are shared across threads. If you want to have multiple threads access the same object then you will need some kind of locking.

Comment: Thank you Amy and sjb, I have been moving that _result in and out of the method, it works for the first event OnRecordsFound, but then the second time OnRecordsFound event is triggered, it complained about the object reference, even though _result, or result when I put it in the method, is populated with correct data. I'm sorry I thought result was lost but apparently the event thought result was lost, or something in that effect.